# error when using wc -c with file names

Tags: string, bash, if-statement, string-length, wc

I am running this code, that sorts files in the desired folders. If a file name has 13 chars it should run the first statement, else the second.

```
for i in *.png; do if [ "$($i | wc -c)" -eq 13 ]; then
    echo cp $i $HOME/Desktop/final/pos_${i:0:1}/${i:0:3}.jpg
else
    echo cp $i $HOME/Desktop/final/pos_${i:0:1}/${i:0:4}.jpg
fi;
done
```

the problem is, that `[ "$($i | wc -c)" -eq 13 ]` is always 0, but clearly, file names have some length. What is the correct way of evaluating `wc -c` in an if statement?

Comment: use quotes in the `cp`. Maybe filename could contain spaces. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
[ "$($i | wc -c)" -eq 13 ]
```

by

```
[ $(printf "%s" "$i" | wc -c) -eq 13 ]
```

or use

```
[ ${#i} -eq 13 ]
```

Comment: where were you before... :P

Comment: for the full collection, also: `((${#i} == 13))` - arithmetic. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `bash` string utilities to get the string length. You don't need `wc` at all. And *double-quote* all variables in script to avoid word-splitting done by the shell.

```
for i in *.png; do 
    if ((${#i} == 13)); then
        echo cp "$i" $HOME/Desktop/final/pos_"${i:0:1}"/"${i:0:3}".jpg
    else
        echo cp "$i" $HOME/Desktop/final/pos_"${i:0:1}"/"${i:0:4}".jpg
    fi
done
```